# generate disjoint sets of Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to group a Spark DataFrame whenever one of multiple columns have equivalent values.
For example, for following df:

```
  val df = Seq(
    ("a1", "b1", "c1"),
    ("a1", "b2", "c2"),
    ("a3", "b2", "c3"),
    ("a4", "b4", "c3"),
    ("a5", "b5", "c5")
  ).toDF("a", "b", "c")
```

I would like a grouping whenever value of `a`, `b` or `c` column matches. In the example DataFrame field `a` of first row matches second row. Field `b` of second matches third and field `c` of third matches fourth row, so they are all in the same set (think `union-find`). Fifth row is a singleton set.

```
val grouped = Seq(
  ("a1", "b1", "c1", "1"),
  ("a1", "b2", "c2", "1"),
  ("a3", "b2", "c3", "1"),
  ("a4", "b4", "c3", "1"),
  ("a5", "b5", "c5", "2")
).toDF("a", "b", "c", "group")
```

I added `group` column as an intuition to a possible disjoint-set result.

Comment: a bit confused about your expected output. why 2 is assigned to the last row? can you explain that logic a little?

Comment: @Raghu indeed. I updated my question

Comment: graphx it will be then...

Comment: did you get a chance to look at the answers? Curious to know what you think

Comment: I still need to give them a look, thanks! I already went away with Spark Graphx to generate a union-find data structure. I might come back to a more ad hoc solution but results look good to be fair...

Comment: thanks for the info. is there any resource where i can understand your Graphx based solution? would be great to know more there.

Comment: sure, I use https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/graphx/lib/ConnectedComponents.html. So, each row is a vertex, and I do a `collect_set` on every column separately, which give me the edges. To get a fully disjoint set, I just need to run mentioned `connectedComponents()` on the constructed graph. I naively assumed it uses union-find underneath but that's very much not guaranteed (in fact, I don't find anything suggesting it does). Might be DFS or something more suitable to Spark...

Comment: great, thanks a lot,will have a look. Give me a feed back when you get a chance to try out the  adhoc solutions. If it helps , upvote and accept the suitable answer, so i get the information archived right :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know.  Basically we replace the values with their occurance count and filter where all is 1. Warning : computationally intensive since collect() is used

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
#Test data
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a1','b1','c1','d1'),('a1','b2','c2','d2'),('a3','b2','c3','d6'),('a4','b4','c3','d7'),('a5','b5','c5','d7'),('a6','b6','c6','d27'),('a9','b88','c54','d71')],schema=['a','b','c','d'])
#%% create a unique id for the records
tst_id = tst.withColumn("id",F.monotonically_increasing_id())
#%% arrays to store the counts for each value. This is computationaly intensive since we bring all data to driver using collect()
val_arr=[]
repl_arr=[]
for x in tst.columns:
    tst_agg = tst.groupby(x).count().collect()    
    val_arr=val_arr+([y[x] for y in tst_agg])
    repl_arr=repl_arr+([y['count'] for y in tst_agg])   

#%% replace the values with their counts,string conversion is based on data type
df_repl = tst_id.replace(map(str,val_arr),map(str,repl_arr))
#%% Note : sum() is inbuilt python function. This is to check if all values are one
df_repl_sum = df_repl.withColumn("sum",sum([F.col(x) for x in tst.columns]))
#%%extract values that has one occurance for all column values
df_select = df_repl_sum.where(F.col('sum')==len(tst.columns))
#%% join with the main data to see the disjoint values
df_res = df_select.select('id','sum').join(tst_id,on='id',how='left')
```

results:

```
+------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|          id|sum|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|146028888064|4.0| a6| b6| c6|d27|
|171798691840|4.0| a9|b88|c54|d71|
+------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If you need a group column, then you change the final join to right and have a column as group based on the sum value : `F.when(F.col('sum')==len(tst.columns),1).otherwise(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add this as a new answer, since I am not so sure about the performance of cube over collect(). but I feel this is better than my previous answer. Try this.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
#Test data
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a1','b1','c1','d1'),('a1','b2','c2','d2'),('a3','b2','c3','d6'),('a4','b4','c3','d7'),('a5','b5','c5','d7'),('a6','b6','c6','d27'),('a9','b88','c54','d71')],schema=['a','b','c','d'])
#%% aggregate and cube the columns and count

tst_res1 = tst.cube('a','b','c','d').count()
# We need count of individual values in columns. so we count how many nulls are there in column
tst_nc = tst_res1.withColumn("null_count",sum([F.when(F.col(x).isNull(),1).otherwise(0) for x in tst_res1.columns]))
# Filter only with 3 null values since we have 4 columns and select values that occur more than once
tst_flt = tst_nc.filter((F.col('null_count')==len(tst.columns)-1)& (F.col('count')>1))
# coalesce to get the elements that occur more than once
tst_coala= tst_flt.withColumn("elements",F.coalesce(*tst.columns))
# collect the elements that occur more than once in an element. 
tst_array = (tst_coala.groupby(F.lit(1)).agg(F.collect_list('elements').alias('elements'))).collect()
#%% convert elements to string, can be skipped for numericals
elements = map(str,tst_array[0]['elements'])
#%% introduce the values that occur more than once as an array in main df
tst_cmp= tst.withColumn("elements_array",F.array(map(F.lit,[x for x in elements])))
# convert the elements into an array
tst_cmp = tst_cmp.withColumn("main_array",F.array(*tst.columns))
#%% find if any of the elements in the row occur more than once in the entire data
tst_result = tst_cmp.withColumn("flag", F.size(F.array_intersect(F.col('main_array'),F.col('elements_array'))))
#%% select the disjoint values
tst_final = tst_result.where('flag=0')
```

results:

```
+---+---+---+---+----------------+-------------------+----+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  elements_array|         main_array|flag|
+---+---+---+---+----------------+-------------------+----+
| a6| b6| c6|d27|[b2, c3, a1, d7]|  [a6, b6, c6, d27]|   0|
| a9|b88|c54|d71|[b2, c3, a1, d7]|[a9, b88, c54, d71]|   0|
+---+---+---+---+----------------+-------------------+----+
```